# Setting a random address breakpoint in gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb, breakpoints

I am learning some **mechanism of breakpoint** and I learned that 'In x86, there exist a instruction called `int3` for debugger to interrupt the CPU. And then CPU will interrupt the running program by `signal`'.

For example:

```
8048e20:   55                      push   %ebp
8048e21:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
```

When the user input

> b *0x8048e21

The instruction will be replaced by `int3`(opcode `0xcc`) and become this:

```
8048e20:   55                      push   %ebp
8048e21:   cc e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
```

And it will stop at the right place.

Then comes the question:

What would happen if I set the breakpoint not at the beginning of a instruction? ie, if I input:

> b *0x8048e22

will debugger still replace the `e5` with `cc`? So I write a simple example and run it with gdb.
[image]

As you can see above, I set two break points and the second is at the middle of a break points. I Input `r` and stop at the first breakpoint and input `c` and run to the end.

So it seems that the gdb ignore the second breakpoint. (For if it really repalce it with a `int3` the program would be totally wrong).

**Question:** What happen to the second breakpoint, more specifically, what does gdb deal with it( or what I learn is wrong?)

**Edit:** @dbrank already give a great example about altering the data field of a instruction, I will try to make it more comprehensive with a similar example (it seems the register).
[image]
**(Any reference about mechanism of breakpoint is appreciated!)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting breakpoint in the middle of instruction will alter the instruction.

See this example of a program, where inserting a breakpoint overwrites original value assigned to variable (42 (0x2a)) with breakpoint instruction (0xcc (204)).

[image: gdb debug inserting breakpoint in middle of instruction]

You can find more about how breakpoints work [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/01/27/how-debuggers-work-part-2-breakpoints).

You can also look into GDB sources (breakpoint.c & infrun.c mostly).

Comment: I tried your example, but my program output the original data? Any ideas?

Comment: Above example was compiled for -m32 flag (for x86). On x86_64 compiled code is a bit different and you need to put a breakpoint at different location (to overwrite original value 0x2a with a breakpoint).

Comment: Sorry to response so late, and your example indeed work. Thanks for your guidance.